# Rails destroy method leaving values in other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that has two models one is vender and the other is purchase_request where vender has has_many :purchase_requests and purchase_request has belongs_to :vender yet when I call destroy it will not delete fields with this vender in it, and thus crashes the application because it returns nil objects where this vender use to be.  how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the `:dependent => :destroy` option for you association.

```
class Vendor < AR::Base
  has_many :purchase_requests, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, it should work for you:

```
  has_many :purchase_requests, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Comment: 'delete' won't trigger any callback which could be a pain if the purchase_request also have dependencies or before_delete filters